# Google Sheet, Finance: FILTER twice to get only one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

I have a Google Sheet with some stock information.

I'm using the formula `GOOGLEFINANCE($B2, "price",TODAY()-15)` to retrieve historical information about a stock (symbol named in `$B2`).

That returns a 2x2 table:

```
Date                 Close
8/25/2017 17:36:00   7.46
```

I only want the 7.46:

Using `=FILTER(GOOGLEFINANCE($B2, "price",TODAY()-15),{FALSE; TRUE})` I get:

```
8/25/2017 17:36:00   7.46
```

I can't see to be able to nest `FILTER` twice.

I checked the documentation. Other than say that I should not use `FILTER` to filter columns and rows in the same call, I didn't get much out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2 filters try:

`=FILTER(FILTER(GOOGLEFINANCE($B2, "price",TODAY()-15),{false;true}),{false,true})`

I prefer query in this case:

`=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE($B2, "price",TODAY()-15),"select Col2 label Col2 ''")`

Also please try this formulas separately:

`={false;true}`

`={false,true}`

and see the result.

Comment: That was not intuitive at all. The last part with the comma vs semi-colon explained everything.

Answer (score 3):

I gather a lot of stock information and always use index to get the stock price.

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE($B2, "price",TODAY()-15),2,2)
```

If you want the date use this. Be sure to format the cell as date or date/time.

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE($B2, "price",TODAY()-15),2,1)
```

Comment: This solution is better for this particular use case, but it's nice to know the general case.